# How to delete rows from a pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, pivot-table, delete-row

I have a `films` table which contains a many to many relation e.g `AgeRatings` with a pivot table called `film_age_rating` which contains a `film_id` as a foreign key I have this with 3 other relations too.

Right now my app has no functionality to make a deletion request to remove a film, so right now I hard delete rows in the `films` DB table. When I delete a film from the `films` table it deletes items, but the data within the pivot table remains unchanged which I don't want to happen.

**films_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('films', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
}
```

**film_age_rating**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('film_age_ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('age_rating_id');
            $table->uuid('film_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

**Film Model**

```
public function ageRatings(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        AgeRatings::class,
        'film_age_rating',
        'film_id',
        'age_rating_id'
    );
}
```

**Age Rating Model**

```
public function film(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Film::class,
        'film_age_rating',
        'age_rating_id',
        'film_id'
    );
}
```

I know an option is to add an `onDelete` cascade to the pivot tables, but that will require lots of migration tables. Is there another way to tackle this without adding a `DELETE` request for now or is adding the cascade the only option?

Could you please advise me on the most efficient option?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine is to use [softDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting)

On this way, there will be only one query to delete a film, and it will be a logical delete.

Comment: So if i was to delete a film from the films table in the database would that delete the data within a pivot table?

Comment: When using `softDeletes` in a model, a column called `deleted_at` is added to your table. If that column has a value (timestamp), Eloquent will not take that register when you use get(), or first(), or paginate(). Your database will still have the relation, but if you use Eloquent instead of \DB for your querys, softDeleted films will not be showed.

Comment: And the other way would be adding ‘onDelete’ to the film I’d on the guest_age_rating table

Answer (score 0):

You can delete data using the **sync()** method. It releases the relation from the pivot table. I assuming that you want to delete a **film**. So this is a sample method in your controller.

```
public function deleteFilm($id)
{
     $film = Film::find($id);
     $film->ageRatings()->sync([]);
     $film->delete();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand this method when you’re adding in logic to delete from the controller e.g which can be called on the front end, but right now I am only wanting to hard delete a row directly in the database from the films table which then deletes the relation data in a pivot linked to that id

Comment: Try to override the delete method in your Film model.